# Python-Snowflake Connector Throwing invalid identifier None

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a script, in which part of it calls to Snowflake on a query. That query is located in an .sql folder and two params are passed through to it in the script. For example:

```
#query.sql
select *
from {some_table}
where
date == '{hit_date}'
and 
id in ({id_list}) or ({id_list}) is null)
```

And the piece of script acts like:

```
def run_query(hit_date, id_list):
    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(**snowflake_creds)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    
    with open(query.sql) as f:
        query = f.read()
    cursor.execute(query.format(hit_date, id_list))
```

The problem comes when the input for 'id_list' is 'None'. I am thrown this error:

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000904 (42000): 019b2591-04da-7b13-0000-89bd25e0043a: SQL compilation error: error line 20 at position 42
> invalid identifier 'NONE'

From my understanding Python's 'None' will automatically convert to SQL's 'Null'. Is this not the case? What should the input for 'id_list' be if 'None/Null'?

Comment: can you show a fully reproducible example? I can't see where you've defined `var1` and `var2_list`

Comment: @SimonDarr I added a bit more clarity with variable names and wrapped code in a function. If this isn't helpful, I can show the whole code but it's broken up in a lot of different places and didn't want to distract from the core logic that I understand is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a clear answer for this specific error. However I was able to work around this by replacing the condition with an impossible value when no list is given.

```
#query.sql
select *
from {some_table}
where
date == '{hit_date}'
and 
(id in ({id_list}) or impossible_value in ({id_list}))
```